# Image over flash object

Tags: html, flash, html-table

Basically I just want to put **new.gif** in the top left corner of the row on my table but I want to sit over my flash object (**loaditem.swf**).

Here is the code I currently have:

```
        <td>
    <img src="new.gif">
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" 
height="100" width="100">
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode"/><param name="movie" value="loadItem.swf" />
<embed height="100" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
quality="high" src="loadItem.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
menu="false" FlashVars="id=50000" wmode="transparent" width="100"></embed></object>
        </td>
        <td>Polar Teddy Bear</td>
```

Also a few images to help see what I need help with:

[image: Current appearance]

What I want to achieve:

[image: Achieve look]

Comment: how about setting up their z-index with image's z-index > flash's z-index. Plus an absolute position from both of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
td {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: The position: relative messes up in IE and firefox though.